# Trying to read data from two files, and subtract values from both files using awk

Tags: awk

I have two files

```
0.975301988947238963     1.75276754663189283     2.00584
0.0457467532388459441    1.21307648993841410     1.21394
-0.664000617674924687    1.57872850852906366     1.71268
-0.812129324498058969    4.86617859243825635     4.93348
```

and

```
1.98005959631337536      -3.78935155011290536    4.27549
-1.04468782080821154     4.99192849476267053     5.10007
-1.47203672235857397     -3.15493073343947694    3.48145
2.68001948430755244      -0.0630730371855307004      2.68076
```

I want to subtract the two values in column 3 of each file.
My first awk statement was

```
**awk
'BEGIN {print "Test"} FNR>1 && FNR==NR { r[$1]=$3; next} FNR>1 { print $3, r[$1],  (r[$1]-$3)}' zzz0.dat zzz1.dat**

Test
5.10007  -5.10007
3.48145  -3.48145
2.68076  -2.68076
```

This suggests it does not recognize r[$1]=$3

I created an additional column xyz by

```
**awk 'NR==1{$(NF+1)="xyz"} NR>1{$(NF+1)="xyz"}1' zzz0.dat**
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Test"} FNR>1 && FNR==NR { xyz[$4]=$3; next} FNR>1 { print $3, xyz[$4],  (xyz[$4]-$3)}' zzz00.dat zzz11.dat 
Test
5.10007 4.93348 -0.16659
3.48145 4.93348 1.45203
2.68076 4.93348 2.25272
```

This now shows three columns, but xyz[$4] is printing only the value in the last column, instead of creating a array.

My real files have thousands of lines. How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: any reason not to use python?

Comment: @balderman python is not a mandatory POSIX tool and so YMMV with whether it exists or can be installed on any Unix box, unlike awk which is a mandatory tool and so exists on all Unix boxes. Also the python code to do this would probably be lengthier and more complicated than the awk code (it certainly won't be less so).

Comment: @Jayashree is that REALLY the output you expect from the 2 input files you posted or is that the output you would expect given 2 different input files that you haven't shown us? If it's the former then please explain the mapping, if it's the latter then please fix your example such that the output is to be expected given the input. Actually, I'm not sure you've shown us expected output at all, I think it's just 2 blocks of unexpected output so far.

Comment: It's not clear if you're trying to subtract $3 values for the same line numbers across the 2 files or for the same $1 values across them (there are no matches on $1 in your example) or some other realtionship - please clarify that in your question too and make sure the example you provide reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it relatively easily using a numeric index for your array. For example:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[++n]=$3; next} o<n{++o; printf "%lf - %lf = %lf\n", a[o], $3, a[o]-$3}' file1 file2
```

That way you preserve the ordering of the records across files. Without a numeric index, the arrays are associative and there is no specific ordering preserved.

**Example Use/Output**

With your files in `file1` and `file2` respectively, you would have:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[++n]=$3; next} o<n{++o; printf "%lf - %lf = %lf\n", a[o], $3, a[o]-$3}' file1 file2
2.005840 - 4.275490 = -2.269650
1.213940 - 5.100070 = -3.886130
1.712680 - 3.481450 = -1.768770
4.933480 - 2.680760 = 2.252720
```

Let me know if that is what you intended or if you have any further questions. If I missed your intent, drop a comment and I will help further.

Answer (score 0):

if the records are aligned in both files, easiest is

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $3,$6,$3-$6}'

2.00584 4.27549 -2.26965
1.21394 5.10007 -3.88613
1.71268 3.48145 -1.76877
4.93348 2.68076 2.25272
```

if you're only interested in the difference, change to `print $3-$6`.